# CSS Column Overlap/Overflow

Tags: css, overflow, z-index, column-count

I have a question about using absolutely positioned divs in CSS columns.
Basically, I have a menu system that uses an unorganised list with count-count 2 applied. On hover of one of the li elements, I want an absolutely positioned div to appear - which it does. But it seems to be overlapped by the second column, making it unusable. See screenshot here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYuUE.png

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li>
    <a href="#">Internal Storage Solutions</a>
    <div class="drop">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Some Link</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The pale blue element you can see highlighted in developer tools is what I need to have visible. I've tried z-index, but it doesn't seem to work here, so I'm wondering if it's some weird column behaviour maybe?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why the dropdown doesn't show up is because it's hidden inside the containing `<li>`. I came up with a solution where I moved the dropdown `<div>` to after the associated `<li>` and used JavaScript to show/hide the dropdown. `column-count` doesn't seem to work on StackOverflow's code snippets, so here's a CodePen: http://codepen.io/phantomesse/pen/OPvyGY